# DockerのMariaDBに突然つながらなくなります。

Tags: docker, mariadb

Dockerの勉強でPC(Windows 10 Pro)にPHPのコンテナとMariaDBのコンテナを立てて開発をはじめました。

PHPのコンテナからもWindows(A5SQLというツール)からもMariaDBに接続してデータを操作できますが、しばらく開発を続けていると突然A5SQLで接続できなくなり、以下のメッセージが表示されます。

```
Lost connection to MySQL server during query
Error on data reading from the connection
```

この状態になってもPHPのコンテナからは接続できます。
Docker Desktopを再起動するとまたA5SQLから接続できるようになります。

何が悪いのかわからず原因調査もどこからやっていいかわからない状態です。
経験があったり見当がつく方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授いただければ幸いです。

追記
mariadbはdocker_composeで起動しています。
webサーバーの方はubuntuのイメージにnginxとphpをインストールしたものです。

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx_php:0.1
    container_name: webserver
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./setting/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mariadb/server:10.3
    container_name: testdb
    ports:
      - 13306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./db/data:/var/lib/mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: testdbpass
```

追記2
同じdocker-comoposeをMacで試したところこの現象は発生しませんでした。
windowsとほぼ同時に起動して、しばらくしてwindowsの方では接続できなくなりましたが
macのほうでは接続できる状態が続いています。

Comment: どのようにmariadbのコンテナを起動していますか？また、どのようにA5SQLを起動していますか？[編集](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/56374/edit)ボタンから追記をお願いします。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。補足を追記いたしました。A5SQLはwindowsのアプリケーションですのでダブルクリックで起動しています。localhostで接続しています。

Comment: DBへの接続とは具体的にどんな操作を行っていますか？ (ただのログイン or 時間のかかるクエリ発行etc) / MariaDB側でのログファイルもチェックしてみるとよさそうです。

Comment: cubickさんコメントありがとうございます。mariadbログを探してみましたが公式イメージのデフォルトではエラーログは出さないようでそのまま使っておりました。重いクエリではありません。コネクションを確立する時に失敗しています。mariadbを再起動してもコンテナを再起動してもこの現象は直らず、docker desktopを再起動しないといけないのでdockerのネットワークが何かおかしくなっているのではと考えています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

すいません、自己解決しました。
根本的な原因は不明ですが、どうやらA5SQLとの相性が悪かったようです。
MySQL Workbenchに変えたらこの現象はおきなくなりました。